# Pass data between a container and its children components in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I have a `<Container />` component that takes a list of `<Card />` as children:

```
<Container>
  <Card />
  <Card />
</Container>
```

`<Card />` has a boolean state `openExpansion` that I want once changed, all sibling `<Card />` would change to the same value. What is the best way to achieve that?
Obviously I can have `openExpansion` as `<Container />` state and inject it to each `<Card />`. Also I don't want to use redux store as I don't know where `<Container />` will be called. But is there a way to keep  `openExpansion` as `<Card />` state while achieving the same effect?
Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you already know what the arguably best solution is, move the bool to the parent's state. But can you tell us *why* you don't want to do that?

Comment: @ChrisG No, I don't know the best solution, and that's the point of the discussion.

Comment: You mentioned the best solution *in your question*. Again: move the bool to the parent, like at least three of the answers here are recommending. If you don't want do to that, tell us *WHY* not.

Comment: @ChrisG because in this way, <Card /> will always rely on props passed from <Container /> and it is better called <ContainerCard /> rather than a more generalizable <Card /> component. It'd be nice to have a solution to achieve the generalisability. But maybe there's no way to do that.

Comment: Without an external wrapper of some kind (parent Component, Context, redux, etc.), children cannot communicate with each other.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share the same value between siblings, you should put openExpansion props in each of the child. 
Also if you want to change the openExpansion you can create a function in Container

```
class Container extends React.Component{
    ....
    state = {
        openExpansion: true
    }

    changeOpenExpansionValue = (value) => this.setState({openExpansion:value})
    render(
        <div>

        <Card openExpansion={this.state.openExpansion} 
            toggleOpenExpansion={this.changeOpenExpansionValue }/>

        <Card openExpansion={this.state.openExpansion} 
            toggleOpenExpansion={this.changeOpenExpansionValue }/>
        </div>    

    )

}
```

any time you want to change all the values from one child component just call `this.props.toggleOpenExpansion(boolValue)` from your Cards

You can't keep openExpansion value locally in each Card as it would be stored and accessible only inside of Card component and might differ from values in siblings

Answer (score 0):

Just create a state in the main component and pass the function to update state to Card. Something like

```
   const App = () => {

   const [openExpansion, setOpenExpansion] = React.useState(false);

   return (
     <Container>
     <Card setOpenExpansion={setOpenExpansion} openExpansion={openExpansion} />
      <Card />
    <Card setOpenExpansion={setOpenExpansion} openExpansion={openExpansion} /><Card /> /* Similar to above card */
     </Container>
    );
   };

  const Card = ({setOpenExpansion openExpansion})  => {
    return (
       <div onClick={() => openExpansion(true)}>
            {openExpansion ? "opened" : ""}
       </div>
    );
  }
```

If I'm getting correctly this is something that you want to achieve by passing setState, state variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you explained one option which is having one variable in Container and passing it into every Card component. Another option is to use a static property inside the Card component. Every Card instance would have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have to lift your state up: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

So in your case, you can create a method/function where you wrap these cards.

```
class WrappedCards extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleOpenExpansion= this.handleOpenExpansion.bind(this);
    this.state = {openExpansion : false};
  }

  handleOpenExpansion(value) {
    this.setState({openExpansion : value});
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <Container>
        <Card
          handleOpenExpansion={this.handleOpenExpansion} />
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```